PCIe Bus Error - Thunderbolt 4 Bridge?
Some reference first.  I got a HP Zbook Power 16 G11 A with Ubuntu about a week ago and have had zero issues.  My HP Thunderbolt G4 120W dock came in two days ago and almost instantly my dmesg log filled up with a ton of PCIe Bus errors.
cactus@cactus-ZBookPower:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.10
Release:    24.10
Codename:   oracular

All packages, drivers, and firmware are up to date.  This also includes the dock.
sudo apt update
Fetched 424 kB in 3s (151 kB/s)     
All packages are up to date. 

dmesg output
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:07:04.0
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:   device [8086:0b26] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:07:04.0
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:   device [8086:0b26] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:07:04.0
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:   device [8086:0b26] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:07:04.0
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
[Thu Oct 24 19:55:27 2024] pcieport 0000:07:04.0:   device [8086:0b26] error status/mask=00000080/00002000

lspci -tv output
cactus@cactus-ZBookPower:~$ lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
           +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
           +-01.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
           +-01.2-[01]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
           +-01.3-[02]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-02.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
           +-02.1-[03]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
           +-02.2-[04]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852CE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
           +-02.4-[05]----00.0  KIOXIA Corporation NVMe SSD Controller BG5 (DRAM-less)
           +-03.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
           +-03.1-[06-65]--
           +-04.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
           +-04.1-[66-c5]----00.0-[67-c5]--+-00.0-[68]--
           |                               +-01.0-[69-87]--
           |                               +-02.0-[88-a6]--
           |                               +-03.0-[a7-c4]--
           |                               \-04.0-[c5]----00.0  Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller (2) I225-LMvP
           +-08.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
           +-08.1-[c6]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Phoenix3
           |            +-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
           |            +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h (Model 74h) CCP/PSP 3.0 Device
           |            +-00.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
           |            +-00.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
           |            +-00.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
           |            +-00.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
           |            \-00.7  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 164a
           +-08.2-[c7]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
           |            \-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] AMD IPU Device
           +-08.3-[c8]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
           |            +-00.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
           |            +-00.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1
           |            +-00.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Pink Sardine USB4/Thunderbolt NHI controller #1
           |            \-00.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Pink Sardine USB4/Thunderbolt NHI controller #2
           +-14.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
           +-14.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
           +-18.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
           +-18.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
           +-18.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
           +-18.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
           +-18.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
           +-18.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
           +-18.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
           \-18.7  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7

I've read various threads on this but most of them are layer 1 / physical layer while mine is Data-Link / Layer 2.  I don't see any apparent issues with the dock.  The display ports work, HDMI works, 2.5Gb Ethernet is fine, as well as all of the USB ports. I was hoping someone could help me out here and it would be much appreciated.
